# Laravel - unable to run migrations on google cloud

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-sql, artisan-migrate

I was able to run migrations on my local mysql. But I was not able to do it on the google cloud SQL instance. What am I missing here?

I've tried to add all relevant information here. But please let me know if you need more details.

I wrote a route to check that I can connect to the database and it works. 
So, I don't think this is a problem with my .env file.

```
Route::get('/dbtest', function() {
    if(DB::Connection()->getDatabaseName()) {
        echo "connected to DB " . DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
    }
});
```

Here are the errors from the log files.

```
    [2020-05-03 08:51:50] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = aimforthesky and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE') {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = aimforthesky and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE') at /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671)
    [stacktrace]
    #0 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(631): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from i...', Array, Object(Closure))
    #1 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(339): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run('select * from i...', Array, Object(Closure))
    #2 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/MySqlBuilder.php(18): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->select('select * from i...', Array)
    #3 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/DatabaseMigrationRepository.php(169): Illuminate\\Database\\Schema\\MySqlBuilder->hasTable('migrations')
    #4 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(608): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\DatabaseMigrationRepository->repositoryExists()
    #5 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php(93): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator->repositoryExists()
    #6 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php(64): Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand->prepareDatabase()
    #7 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(541): Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand->Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\{closure}()
    #8 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php(81): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator->usingConnection(NULL, Object(Closure))
    #9 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand->handle()
    #10 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(33): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #11 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(36): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
    #12 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(91): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
    #13 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(35): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
    #14 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(592): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
    #15 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(134): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
    #16 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
    #17 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
    #18 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(912): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
    #19 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(264): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
    #20 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(140): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
    #21 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(93): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
    #22 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
    #23 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
    #24 {main}
    [previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory at /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70)
    [stacktrace]
    #0 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(70): PDO->__construct('mysql:unix_sock...', 'root', '', Array)
    #1 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(46): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector->createPdoConnection('mysql:unix_sock...', 'root', '', Array)
    #2 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php(24): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector->createConnection('mysql:unix_sock...', Array, Array)
    #3 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php(182): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\MySqlConnector->connect(Array)
    #4 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\{closure}()
    #5 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(926): call_user_func(Object(Closure))
    #6 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(961): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->getPdo()
    #7 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(405): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->getReadPdo()
    #8 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(331): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->getPdoForSelect(true)
    #9 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(664): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->Illuminate\\Database\\{closure}('select * from i...', Array)
    #10 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(631): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from i...', Array, Object(Closure))
    #11 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(339): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run('select * from i...', Array, Object(Closure))
    #12 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/MySqlBuilder.php(18): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->select('select * from i...', Array)
    #13 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/DatabaseMigrationRepository.php(169): Illuminate\\Database\\Schema\\MySqlBuilder->hasTable('migrations')
    #14 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(608): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\DatabaseMigrationRepository->repositoryExists()
    #15 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php(93): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator->repositoryExists()
    #16 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php(64): Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand->prepareDatabase()
    #17 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(541): Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand->Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\{closure}()
    #18 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php(81): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator->usingConnection(NULL, Object(Closure))
    #19 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand->handle()
    #20 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(33): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
    #21 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(36): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
    #22 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(91): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
    #23 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(35): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
    #24 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(592): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
    #25 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(134): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
    #26 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
    #27 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))#28 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(912): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
    #29 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(264): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
    #30 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(140): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
    #31 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(93): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
    #32 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
    #33 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
    #34 {main}
    "}
```

This is what I have in my service providers list in config/app.php

```
       /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
```

This is what I have in my .env file

```
APP_NAME=MyAppName
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:MyAppKey=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
#DB_HOST=192.168.10.10
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=db_username
DB_PASSWORD=db_password
DB_SOCKET=/cloudsql/project_name:region:cloud_db_instance
#MYSQL_DSN="mysql://db_user:db_password@db_name?unix_socket=/cloudsql/project_name:region:db_instance_name"

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
```

Comment: Do you have any view composer or some service executing queries in the register or boot method in a service provider?

Comment: Thanks for the tip Helder. Helped me realize that it had to be something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually with the .env file

Using this worked for me.

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
```

This did not work.

```
DB_SOCKET=/cloudsql/project_name:region:cloud_db_instance
```

Of course, you also need this bit.

```
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=db_username
DB_PASSWORD=db_password
```